# Prestashop price.js modification

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop

This is my first post.
I am trying to move move customization to the newest version of Prestashop.
One of modifications was in price.js (/js/price.js line 50) but in newest version of Prestashop that file is moved.

Anyway I was trying to mod /js/admin/prize.js on line 50 but code is breaking other price calculations and I don't know why. Can you help me with this?

```
function calcPrice()
{
    var priceType = $('#priceType').val();
    if (priceType == 'TE')
        calcPriceTI();
    else
        calcPriceTE();
}
function calcCalc(){
    var checkboxCalc = $('#calculator_on').is(':checked');
    var tabCalc = $('#tableCalculator');
    if(checkboxCalc)
        tabCalc.show('fast')
    else
        tabCalc.hide('fast')
}
function calcBox(){
    var box = parseInt($('#quantity_box').val());
    if(box > 0)
        $('#quantity_box').val(box);
    else
        $('#quantity_box').val(1);
}

function calcMetr(){
    var metr = parseFloat($('#quantity_metr').val());

    if(metr > 0)
        $('#quantity_metr').val(metr.toFixed(3));
    else
        $('#quantity_metr').val(1);

}
```